# Website down: main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user '(removed)'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: magento2, sql

The following is the complete error in the log:

main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user '(removed)'@'localhost' (using password: YES) {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user '(removed)'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at /home/(removed)/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:144, PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user '(removed)'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at /home/(removed)/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:128)"} []

I have tried many solutions but nothing worked, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you do anything ,such as an upgrade or add a module, before this error? Did you check etc/env.php for the correct DB username and password? Would the username or password on the database have changed for any reason?

Comment: yes, I did installed a module via admin panel added via the marketplace-magento.

Just now I opened the env.php file and I have noticed that my database username is the same but passport is different. Shall I change it?

P.S I am a non-tech guy.

Comment: Changed the password in etc/env.php.

Site is working now.

Thank you for this kind help.

Cheers.

Comment: I added my comment as an answer, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

Answered in the comments:

Check to make sure the database username and password are correct in etc/env.php

Comment: Changed the password in etc/env.php
It's working now. 
Thank you.